# How to change color , etc. on heat map

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry for as newbie question. I am try to make a heat map graphs. Here is what I got:

[image]

It looks ugly. I wonder whether I could choose the color for graph. If so, how? I would like to use yellow-red color instead of blue one, and red has most obs. Also any way to make this graph looks nicer and more professional? Any example codes will help me a lot in learning this type graph. Also, my variables are not continuous. How should I fix it show it won't set as 1.5, 2.5?

Here are my sample data and codes I wrote:

```
ID<- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
Group<-c("A","B","C","D","D","D","A","B","D","C","B","D","A","A","C","B","B","B")
Color<-c("Green","Blue","Red","Red","Black","Yellow","Green","Green","Yellow","Purple","Red","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Green","Red","Red","Green")
Realy_Love<-c("Y","N","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y")
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Group, Color, Realy_Love)
        
Sample.data %>%
  count(Group, Color, sort = TRUE) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = Color, fill=n)) + geom_raster() +
geom_text(aes(label = paste0("N=",round(n, 1)), color = n < 100),show.legend = F)+
  guides(fill = guide_legend())
```

Many thanks.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions make in the answer's section, a good resource to keep always in mind is the R graph gallery: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/
There you'll find charts and examples made with R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would do to improve the appearance here. Firstly, set the colour of the tiles with `scale_fill_manual`. Secondly, make the tiles square with `coord_equal`. Third, make the text black instead of red. Fourth, set the theme elements to the `theme_minimal` setting.

This may not be to everyone's taste of course, but is certainly better to my eye. I think you might want to try a less vivid mix of colours for a more professional look.

```
Sample.data %>%
  count(Group, Color, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = Color, fill = factor(n, levels = 3:1))) + 
  geom_raster() +
geom_text(aes(label = paste0("N=",round(n, 1))), 
          color = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend("n")) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "orange", "red")) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: I would prefer a 'brewer' color-scheme. i.e.: [YlOrRd](https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=YlOrRd&n=3), `scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'YlOrRd')`.

Comment: Thanks. We have the same taste. :P One problem, my obs  is not continuous variable, how should I change it ? the legend suggest it as continuous with 1.5, 2.5 in it.

Comment: @Stataq you just use a `guide_colorbar` instead of `guide_legend`. I have updated to show this.

Comment: It still has 1.5, 2.5 in it after I change it to guide_colorbar. I thought I saw it changed to 1, 2, 3 for a second in the updated post. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you meant Stataq. I have updated again

Comment: Thanks so much. One more question, is it possible to assign a set of color instead of c("yellow", "orange", "red")? If I have more than 3 levels, such as 10 levels, and I would like to have them in same color group from light to dark without enter the color name one by one?

Comment: @Stataq you can use a palette function. In your case, you could do `heat.colors(10)` to get 10 colors, etc